# memcache - fetch items without affecting their counter (LRU)

Tags: memcached

I want to retrieve data from memcache without affecting the LRU. Is there a way to fetch the items without changing their counter "timestamp"?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a specific command that will allow you to do this. One option would be to just remove the key from the cache after you get it if you know that you won't need it for a long time.